# "msg": "winrm or requests is not installed: No module named xmltodict"

Tags: ansible

I have Ansible version 2.4.2. Trying to integrate Ansible controller machine (Linux) with Windows. Checked and installed all the pre-requesties.

However, I'm getting the error below while connecting to windows machine:

```bash
ansible *<windowsservername>* -i inventory -m win_ping
*windowsservername* | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "winrm or requests is not installed: No module named xmltodict"
}
```

The following are the installed packages

```bash
pip freeze | grep -i xmltodict
xmltodict==0.11.0

pip freeze | grep -i winrm
pywinrm==0.3.0
```

I am new to ansible, please help on this issue.

Answer (score 6):

It worked for me.
I reinstalled *winrm* on the controller machine using:

```bash
pip install --ignore-installed pywinrm
```

Comment: don't use answer to add "me too" comments. Please delete the answer and create a separate question properly explained